# Why does Magento 1.9.3.10 does not include /lib/mcrypt_compat/mcrypt.php

Tags: magento1.9.3, php-7.2, mcrypt

Magento released a patch for magento 1.9.3.x to be able to support php7.2. The patch includes /lib/mcrypt_compat/mcrypt.php so that php7.2 which does not have the mcrypt module (at least officially), can run without problems.

However i just notice that Magento 1.9.3.10 actually does not include this mcrypt lib, which means you either have to install mcrypt for php7.2 with pear, extract the file from a Magento 1.9.3.9 installation or use php7.1 which has mcrypt.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

According to Inchoo (they guys that created the Magento patch for PHP 7), the PHP 7.2 patch was created before the 1.9.3.10 version but not included.

However, Magento 1.9.4.0 will include a revised core with the PHP 7.2 patch built in.

[Source: Link to github](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/issues/151)